# Two similiar music chest web shops with the same products and no impressum - both are a fraud?

Tags: fraud, scams, websites, online-shopping

I wanted to buy a tiny litte music box as a present for christmas since I discovered an advertisement of this website on Facebook: https://www.musicchests.com/
This is their facebook page btw: https://www.facebook.com/musicchests/?ref=br_rs

Neither the website nor the facebook page say anaything about where the company is situated. Any web page missing an impressum is somewhat suspicious in my opinion. In Austria, the country where I live, basically every website needs an impressum. Furthermore, there are comments [like this one](https://www.facebook.com/musicchests/videos/1944495359132532/?comment_id=1979860722262662) on the facebook page saying that someone ordered a product but has not received a confirmation or the product itself.

Not only that, I discovered a similiar page featuring the same products:
https://www.inveniocrafts.com/ There is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PM_W0qUBCb8) which as the company name in the title and which is the same video that can be found in the facebook page of musicchests.com. 
But again, no impressum on the website.

**My question:** Given the details I have stated, are both of these pages, musicchest.com and inveniocrafts.com, both a scam?

Comment: This "impressum" thing seems to be local to Germany & Austria.  I'd never heard of it before, but my experience is mostly US based sites.

Comment: Questions about very specific providers like this are generally off-topic, see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lack of "About us" is veery unusual.

I pretended to buy something, and the checkout page had a Terms of Service link, which I clicked on and read.  There's a Post Office box which I googled.  It turns out to be Stacks Design, PO Box 12113, San Francisco, CA 94112

http://www.shopstacks.com/stacks/

I wouldn't buy from them, though, because they're pretty spartan.